# My Express MySQL server get crash when user input wrong data for login

Tags: mysql, express

When the user try to login with wrong email or password my app throw error user not found if the email is not in dB a other error then password is wrong but after few second the server get crashed with the error

> "SERVER CONNECTION LOST"

I was Thing the problem come in my error handling but after many try and search i'm now block

```
export const getUser = (req, res) => {
const token = req.cookies.accessToken;
if (!token) return res.status(401).json("Please logging first !");


    jwt.verify(token, "secretkey", (err, data) =\> {
    if (err) {
    return res.status(403).json("Please login first !!");
    }
    
        const q = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE ID= ?";
        
        db.query(q, [req.params.userId], (err, data) => {
          if (err) return res.status(500).json("Something when wrong !!");
          const { user_PassCode, ...info } = data[0];
          if(data) return res.json(info);
        });
    });
    };

//...........LOGIN START HERE...............

export const logIn = (req, res) => {

    const q = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_Email = ? "

    db.query(q, [req.body.user_Email], (err, data) => {
        if (err)  res.status(500).json(err) 
        if(data.length === 0) res.status(404).json('user not found!')

            // chech if password match to userPasscode
        const checkPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(
            req.body.user_PassCode,
            data[0].user_PassCode
        )
       
        if(!checkPassword) return res.status(400).json('wrong password or username try again!') 
       
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: data[0].ID }, "secretkey")
        const {user_PassCode, ...others} = data[0]
        
            // if not error 
            res.cookie("accessToken", token, {
                httpOnly: true
            }).status(200).json(others)
    })
}
```

Comment: Try add return before `res.status(500).json(err)` and before `res.status(404).json('user not found!')`

Comment: Thanks you man !! I really appreciate you help you can't imagine how this missing return wasted my time